# Spring cloud config directory structure not picked up

Tags: spring, configuration, spring-cloud-config

We are setting up a mono repository with all our application properties. We want have a structure in our git like `{application}/{application}-{profile}.application`

We tried couple of configurations but non of them are working:

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.searchPaths= '*'
spring.cloud.config.server.git.searchPaths= '{application}'
spring.cloud.config.server.git.searchPaths= '{application}/*'
```

Can someone help me with this issue? The documentation itself does not specify much about the searchPaths property.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue. The searchPaths need to be without the '.

This fixed my problem:

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.searchPaths= {application}
```

**Update** :

For multiple directory,names should be comma-separated.